# Метод startActivity из фона

Tags: java, android

Проблема вроде как должна быть известна, но нужного решения я так найти и не смог.

Опишу сценарий:

В некотором FirstActivity происходит запрос к API, по положительному результату которого вызывается startActivity() в SecondActivity. Проблема заключается в том, что если во время отправки запроса свернуть приложение в фон (то есть startActivity() будет вызываться в фоне), то:

1. Если версия android >= 29, то startActivity() в принципе не сработает. Сработает идущий за startActivity() finish() и при повторном запуске приложение перезапустится (что логично)
2. Если версия android < 29, то startActivity() сработает и поднимет на передний план эту самую SecondActivity.
   Исходя из этого заключается вопрос. Как заставить приложение независимо от версии переходить между activity и не поднимать их на передний план?

`Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); startActivity(intent); finish();`

Comment: Делать проверку на версию и по результату выполнять нужные действия.

Comment: @DrMcSheen, это то я понимаю, тут вопрос какие действия.